# iOS build fails with `Exception: Unity.IL2CPP.Building.BuilderFailedException...` on Unity Editor 2021.3.10f1 for Apple silicon

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I am trying to build for iOS with Unity Editor 2021.3.10f1 but it fails with

```
Exception: Unity.IL2CPP.Building.BuilderFailedException: Build failed with 0 successful nodes and 0 failed ones
Error: Internal build system error. Backend exited with code 2.
tundra: error: Failed to open file "/Users/masafumi/Documents/GrialSampleScenes 2/Library/Il2cppBuildCache/iOS/buildstate/tundra.log.json" for structured logging

   at il2cpp.Program.DoRun(String[] args, RuntimePlatform platform, Il2CppCommandLineArguments il2CppCommandLineArguments, BuildingOptions buildingOptions, Boolean throwExceptions) in /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/il2cpp/il2cpp/Program.cs:line 339
UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunProgram (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs:129)
UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunNetCoreProgram (System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser, System.Action`1[T] setupStartInfo) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs:91)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.RunIl2CppWithArguments (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] arguments, System.Action`1[T] setupStartInfo) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:817)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.ConvertPlayerDlltoCpp (UnityEditor.Il2Cpp.Il2CppBuildPipelineData data) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:801)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.Run () (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:639)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPUtils.RunIl2Cpp (System.String tempFolder, System.String stagingAreaData, UnityEditorInternal.IIl2CppPlatformProvider platformProvider, System.Action`1[T] modifyOutputBeforeCompile, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry runtimeClassRegistry) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:279)
UnityEditor.iOS.PostProcessiPhonePlayer.CrossCompileManagedDlls (UnityEditor.iOS.PostProcessiPhonePlayer+BuildSettings bs, UnityEditor.iOS.PostProcessiPhonePlayer+ProjectPaths paths, UnityEditor.AssemblyReferenceChecker checker, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport buildReport) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/iPhonePlayer/Extensions/Common/BuildPostProcessor.cs:932)
UnityEditor.iOS.PostProcessiPhonePlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.iOS.PostProcessiPhonePlayer+BuildSettings bs, UnityEditor.iOS.PostProcessiPhonePlayer+ProjectPaths paths, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport buildReport) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/iPhonePlayer/Extensions/Common/BuildPostProcessor.cs:755)
UnityEditor.iOS.PostProcessiPhonePlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.iOS.PostProcessorSettings postProcessorSettings, UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/iPhonePlayer/Extensions/Common/BuildPostProcessor.cs:695)
UnityEditor.iOS.iOSBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/iPhonePlayer/Extensions/Common/ExtensionModule.cs:45)
Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
UnityEditor.iOS.iOSBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/iPhonePlayer/Extensions/Common/ExtensionModule.cs:49)
UnityEditor.Modules.DefaultBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Modules/DefaultBuildPostprocessor.cs:28)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.Int32 subtarget, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:370)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)
```

```
Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 11 seconds (10834 ms)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)
```

```
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 2 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002ce] in /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:193 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:94 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)
```

I searched but couldn't find the solution or known issues.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

My environment

```
macOS Monterey 12.5
Unity Editor 2021.3.10f1 Silicon
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well... I found the solution and will leave it here for someone who faces the same issue in the future.

You just need to remove `Il2cppBuildCache` folder under Library.([ref](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/il2cpp-ios-build-fails-when-building-on-a-different-machine-slash-user-due-to-il2cppbuildcache-caching))

I think this issue was happening because I moved the project to another folder.

Comment: Great, this fixed my problem on iOS too.
You could mark your answer as accepted by ticking the "V" symbol and this might help other users who will find the answer useful.
Thank you for sharing the solution @Masa

Comment: You are genius, I already spent 2 days with this problem

Answer (score 3):

**Hello here's the solution if you change or move the project.**

Remove **Il2cppBuildCache** folder (Project/Library/Il2cppBuildCache)

Mostly this issue occurs when we **change** the project location or **moved** the project to another location.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33107469)

Comment: Oh my god you saved my bascon thank you, this is one of those super painful errors that makes no sense and is almost impossbile to work out!!!